# Update the Value by matching Name

Tags: r

I have a old_df looks like

```
old_df <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "A","A","B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E"), 
             Value = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5))
```

And I want to update this old_df with new updated values by keeping Name not in new data.

```
new <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "E",), 
             Value = c(100, 500))
```

New Output will look like

```
A 100
A 100
A 100
B 2
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 500
E 500
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` and replace `NA` returned from unmatched values with the old values, i.e.

```
old_df$new_val <- new$Value[match(old_df$Name, new$Name)]
old_df$new_val[is.na(old_df$new_val)] <- old_df$Value[is.na(old_df$new_val)]
```

Or using *dplyr*,

```
library(dplyr)

old_df %>% 
 left_join(new, by = 'Name') %>% 
 mutate(Value.y = replace(Value.y, is.na(Value.y), Value.x[is.na(Value.y)]))
```

both giving,

> ```
>    Name Value new_val
> 1    A     1     100
> 2    A     1     100
> 3    A     1     100
> 4    B     2       2
> 5    B     2       2
> 6    C     3       3
> 7    D     4       4
> 8    E     5     500
> 9    E     5     500
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using a join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(old_df)[new,  Value := i.Value, on = .(Name)]
old_df
#   Name Value
#1:    A   100
#2:    A   100
#3:    A   100
#4:    B     2
#5:    B     2
#6:    C     3
#7:    D     4
#8:    E   500
#9:    E   500
```